# Regex expression which match a display name which starts and end with an alphabets

Tags: javascript

Couldn't find my exact need on SO and I'm still learning regex but this is what i have tried so far:

```
display_name.match(/^[a-zàáèéìíòóùú]([.' -]+[a-zàáèéìíòóùú]+)*$/i);
```

But it's not working correctly.

What i'm trying to achieve is

Display name should start with and end with a letter ( English alphabets and just these ten special letters àáèéìíòóùú only)

May contain "'.- " ( dot, hypen and space, without double quotes)

E.g should match Mr. Benardó, Mrs. àdelaidé adegòke

It's just a display name and region specific.

Comment: Your first char group must also be with `+` as now it must be first only letter, followed by one of `.' -` and then any amount of letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
display_name.match(/^[a-zàáèéìíòóùú]([.'-]?[a-z àáèéìíòóùú]+)*$/i)
```

valid names

```
àdeola
òpaula-brian
Mr. teni teni
```

Invalid are

```
 -mr white
mr--white
mr white'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following pattern

```
/([a-zA-Zàáèéìíòóùú]+[a-zA-Zàáèéìíòóùú. -]+)/gm
```

Keep '-' at the end.

Comment: not working.. It matches ######ab or i guess it needs ^ and $  to match start and end

Comment: this works (/^([a-zA-zàáèéìíòóùú.-]+[a-zA-zàáèéìíòóùú. -]+)$/i) however it will also match -. at the beginning and end which is not what i want

Comment: It works as expected. check this out : https://regex101.com/r/aXfvCx/2
I have made one minor correction,

Comment: it works unfortunately, this also match: --Mrs. àdegoke. (Note the hyphen before Mrs)

Comment: You only said it may contain - as well. If you don't want - should not be in that starting of the same remote it from staring group. Also remove '.' . Keep it like this /([a-zA-Zàáèéìíòóùú]+[a-zA-Zàáèéìíòóùú. -]+)/gm

Comment: @Shreekesh...your version works now. Thanks

Comment: @Theconcise If it works for you, you can accept the answer.